# asp.net ListView from Linq to show NavigationLinks

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview, hyperlink

When a user logs in, I would like to present them with a list of their current records (requests). My asp.net is this-

```
        <asp:ListView ID="MySavedRequestsListView" runat="server" GroupItemCount="5">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server" id="table1">
                    <tr runat="server" id="groupPlaceholder">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr runat="server" id="tableRow">
                    <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="TrUserRequest" runat="server">
                    <td id="TdTitle" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>'
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

and code behind is:

```
            var UserRequests =  (from r in context.course_requests
                                where r.requestor_userid == access.username
                                orderby r.course_title
                                select new { r.request_id, 
                                            r.title}).ToList();
            MySavedRequestsListView.DataSource = UserRequests;
            MySavedRequestsListView.DataBind();
```

I am presented with a nice list of course titles, but what I want is for those titles to navigate to another page, using the request_id as the parameter. How can I incorporate the HyperLink class into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="http://www.site.com/page.aspx?id=<%#Eval("request_id") %>" Text="<%#Eval("title") %>"  runat="server" />
```

or a simple `<a>` tag

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/page.aspx?id=<%#Eval("request_id") %>"> <%#Eval("title") %> </a>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is there a way to do it where I define the NavigateUrl  property in the code behind? I've tried the HyperLink but get a 'The Server Tag is not well formed' error.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, use this 
`<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='http://www.site.com/page.aspx?id=<%#Eval("request_id") %>' Text='<%#Eval("title") %>'  runat="server" />`

Comment: Yes, I messed around with quotes too. I can get it to run the page without an error, but if I do then the <%#Eval("request_id") %> appears literally in the URL, rather than the actual id. Like this- <asp:HyperLink ID="RequestHyperLink" NavigateUrl="~/RequestSummary.aspx?id=<%#Eval('request_id') %>" Text="Something" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink> produces a URL like-

Comment: http://localhost:64876/NewCourseRequestSummary.aspx?id=<%#Eval('course_request_id') %>

Comment: <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="http://www.site.com/page.aspx?id=<%#Container.Title%>" Text="<%#Container.request_id%>" runat="server" />

Comment: This worked: NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("course_request_id", "~/NewCourseRequestSummary.aspx?id={0}") %>'